# Rails : Admin approval for user created products

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create admin account, currently using devise gem for user account. On app, users create their products. Admin role will be verify the products and approve them. Products should not be published until admin approves it. I don't know how to go about it.
Can anyone tell the procedure?
It will be great help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install the [rails admin gem](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) (optional, but it is an awesome gem so that you don't have to build an admin panel from scratch)
2. Add a boolean field called `published` to your products table by running `rails g migration add_published_field_to_products published:boolean`
3. Go inside the generated migration file and add `default: false` to the column
4. Run `rake db:migrate`
5. Add a scope to your product model: `scope :published, where(published: true)`

And voila! Now the admin will be able to publish or unpublish your products and in your controllers you can say something like `@products = Product.published` to get all published products.

Comment: hey thanks! will get back on implementing this.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a column `approved`, type boolean to the `Product` set as `false` by default. So only the admin, would be able to see those products.

```
current_user.admin? ? @products = Product.all : @products = Product.where(:approved => false)
```

Than, you can use the same idea to list the products to be approved.

Now you can start trying some code and you can come back when you start facing code problems.

Comment: hey thanks and sure, wil get back on implementation

Answer (score 0):

If u want to implement this on broader level use Ryan Bates cancan gem. You can set roles and control display at view level.